# htaccess change files extension from .php to .html

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created the redirect rule for seo friendly URL's. I want to remove the .php URL from all pages and requests.

I have tried with the below code but it not working:

```
Options -Multiviews

Options +FollowSymLinks

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^special-offers.html$ special_offers.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ offer_detail.php?url=$1


RewriteRule ^sear_search.html$ search.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

I already using this rules in other project and the URL's are working fine, but now it's not workin.

Comment: What are some example URLs that are not working and what is exact error?

Comment: When I want to visit the  **special-offers.html** this will show the **special_offers.php** page with the result. But when I run the **http://localhost/tayyaba/special-offers.html** it's showing the **Object not found!**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^special-offers.html$ special_offers.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^sear_search\.html$ search.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)\.html$ offer_detail.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Your `RewriteBase /` directive is routing it to site root directory instead of current directory.